# How to test swipe/fling event using jUnit in Android testcase

Tags: android, user-interface, testing, robotium

I find that in `android.test.TouchUtils` there is a drag method, I try it, but `onfling()` seems not react to this action. I also try robotium's `scrollToSide(int)`, not working either. Any suggestions that how I can achieve this in my test case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use `MotionEvent` class and it's `obtain()` method to simulate all kinds of swipe/touch gestures. Here's the first tutorial I found on this, it should get you started: http://softteco.blogspot.com/2011/02/touch-hold-swipe-release-gesture.html

Comment: Thanks! I will have a try on that.

Answer (score 4):

*drag(float fromX, float toX, float fromY, float toY, int stepCount)* in [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) does work too, where as swipe and scrollToSide don't seem to work.

Using [android.support.v4.view.ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), following code works for me:

```
solo.drag(300,0,100,100,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the following methods with Robotium. I need to use this hacky way because the v4.view.ViewPager always mades my test suite stop running for some reasons.

```
private void swipeToLeft(int stepCount) {
    Display display = solo.getCurrentActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    float xStart = width - 10 ;
    float xEnd = 10;
    solo.drag(xStart, xEnd, height / 2, height / 2, stepCount);
}

private void swipeToRight(int stepCount) {
    Display display = solo.getCurrentActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    int height = display.getHeight();
    float xStart = 10 ;
    float xEnd = width - 10;
    solo.drag(xStart, xEnd, height / 2, height / 2, stepCount);
}
```

And the whole idea is from this great post from Jason: 
http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2013/02/13/simulating-swipes-in-your-android-tests/